# how to attach jquery plugin to dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, autocomplete, struts

I have a textbox in jsp as follows

```
<input id="newHardware_details_0__hardware_type" name="details[0].hardware_type" class="autocompleter">
```

I am using jquery plugin 'autocomplete' as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTypes = [ "Desktop",
    "Laptop",
    "Mobile",
    "Tablet",
    "Printer",
    "Scanner",
    "Server",
    "Switch",
    "Wifi-router",
    "USB Dongle"
    ];
    $( ".autocompleter" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTypes
    });
  });
```

I have another add button on click of which i want to add simillar text box with 'autocomplete' functionality. i am able to create textbox dynamically from javascript function but not able to attach this jquery plugin autocompleter to it. note that add button can be clicked any number of times and newly generated textbox will have names as follows

details[1].hardware_type

details[2].hardware_type

details[3].hardware_type etc..

Javascript code is as follows:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    //alert ("adding row");
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var idx = rowCount+1;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

var hardware_typeElement = document.createElement("input");
hardware_typeElement.type = "text";
hardware_typeElement.name = "details[" + idx + "].hardware_type";
hardware_typeElement.id = "newHardware_details_" + idx + "__hardware_type";
hardware_typeElement.className = "autocompleter";
cell1.appendChild(hardware_typeElement);

var label = document.createElement("label");
var t = document.createTextNode("Hardware Type");
label.setAttribute("for", "newHardware_details_" + idx + "__hardware_type");
label.appendChild(t);
cell1.insertBefore(label,document.getElementById("newHardware_details_" + idx + "__hardware_type"));



}
```

I am stranger to Jquery. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: If u have jQuery at your disposal, you should consider rewriting all of this code using jquery..

Comment: Actually, you might not need jQuery at all - http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/. You may also want to use this element instead of jqueryui - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist

Comment: thanks both of you for suggestions. both solutions satisfy requirement. but for simplicity i am going ahead with datalist. sometimes it becomes difficult which language to choose when there are multiple languages providing you solution

Answer (score 1):

Something like below will do:

```
$(/*select your td here*/).append('input type="text" class="my-textbox"');
$(/*select same td*/).find('input.my-textbox').callPluginMethod();
```

Update: modified code in question:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
   addRow();
})
function addRow() {
   $(tableID).append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="my-textbox"></input></td></tr>')
   $(tableID).find('tr:last > input.my-textbox').callPluginMethod();
}
```

Comment: thanks pawan. how do i call above 2 lines on button click? say button has id 'trigger'